# What is the difference between a Network Meta-Analysis compared to a standard meta-analysis, MASEM and Meta-Regression?

Tags: meta-analysis

Network Meta analysis is mostly applied within the medical field. What about applying it to the business or marketing field ? Would that be possible ?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify why you doubt its wider applicability.